# VBA Excel Change Value in Field

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have an excel table with a column named "Completed?" that users select Yes or No from the drop down.  If they Select Yes a Message Box using vbOKCancel pops up.  If they confirm Yes that part is working so far, but if anything else happens (they hit Cancel, or X out, etc) I want this field to be changed to "No" - this is what I'm struggling with.
It seems like it should be simple - any ideas?

```
If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then

Dim answer As Integer
answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to mark this as Completed?  This will move the record to the Completed Tab and cannot be undone.", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING")
If answer = vbOK Then MsgBox ("OK")

'need help with this next row
Else: Target.Value = "No"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundimentaily, you issue is missuse of the `If Then Else End IF` structure. (you are mixing Multi Line and Single Line syntax)

[See here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/if-then-else-statement) for more details

There are some other issues too, see inline comments

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult ' use correct data type
    Dim rng As Range, cl As Range

    On Error GoTo EH ' ensure events get turned back on

    Application.EnableEvents = False ' prevent event cascade
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(3)) ' get all cells in column 3 that changed
    For Each cl In rng ' process each changed cell
        If LCase(cl.Value) = "yes" Or LCase(cl.Value) = "y" Then  ' case insensitive
            answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to mark row " & cl.Row & " as Completed?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This will move the record to the Completed Tab and cannot be undone.", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING")
            If answer = vbOK Then
                cl.Value = "Yes" ' Standardise case
                ' MsgBox "OK" ' this is a bit annoying
            Else
                cl.Value = "No"
            End If
        End If
    Next
EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant and way better than I could even hope to do!  I never would've gotten all that on my own.  I'm actually adding a fair bit of already working code to the "If answer = vbOK then..." area, so I'll try combining it all and if it doesn't work I hope I can reach out to you?  Thanks again - you rock!

Comment: @Bri thanks for the feedback.  Happy to help, but if you end up with a new question, it's better to, well, ... ask a new question

Comment: And I added it all together and it works perfectly!!!!  Thanks again so much - I'm not much of a coder but decent at copying and pasting what others post, hence why I was setting the answer as an Integer and other odd mistakes.  Seriously, thank you so much for schooling me - I am in awe of your skills!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
   If Target.Column = 3 And Target.Value = "Yes" Then

      Dim answer As Integer
      answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to mark this as Completed?  " & _
                     "This will move the record to the Completed Tab and cannot be undone.", vbOKCancel + vbCritical, "CRITICAL WARNING")

      If answer = vbOK Then
         MsgBox ("OK")

      Else
         Target.Value = "No"

      End If

   End If
```